# Gulp task gets stuck after i start Redis server in background

Tags: redis, gulp

```
gulpfile.js  

var shell = require('gulp-shell');

gulp.task('startRedis', shell.task([  
  'redis-2.8.15/src/redis-server > /dev/null &'  
]));
```

When i run the above startRedis gulp task, it starts redis server but never exits.

```
$gulp startRedis
[19:03:42] Using gulpfile ~/myhome/gulpfile.js  
[19:03:42] Starting 'startRedis'...
```

If i stop the redis server then it returns. Not sure what is wrong, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you just want the task to finish immediately, you may be better-off using `child_process.exec` directly:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

gulp.task('startRedis', function() {
  exec('redis-2.8.15/src/redis-server', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err, stdout, stderr);
    }
  });
});
```

If you want gulp to exit immediately, thus creating a zombie redis-server process, that may be more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I have been used gulp-shell to launch my redis server, but it was not launch every time before my node app

With `exec = require('child_process').exec;`

I can do it safer

```
gulp.task('dev-redis', function() {
    exec('redis-server --port 7777 --notify-keyspace-events KExe', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log(stdout);
        console.log(stderr);
    });
});
gulp.task('dev',['dev-redis'], function() {

    /*
    * Add on('change').on('restart') allow to add listeners
    * Even if you don't precise callback functions, it triggers the change/restart event
    * */
    nodemon({ script: 'index.js', nodeArgs: ['--debug'], env: { 'NODE_ENV': 'development' }  })
        .on('change', [])
        .on('restart', function () {
            console.log('restarted!');
        });
});
```